# Exponential distribution is self-decomposable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to prove that if $X$ has an exponential distribution then it is self-decomposable and I need to prove it in two ways.

I've already proved it by using Paul-Lévy theorem which says that:

$X$ is self-decomposable $\iff $$(\forall c\in[0,1])$ $(\exists Y_{c} \perp X)$ $X=cX+Y_{c}$

I guess that the second way would be by finding such sequence of independent random variables $Z_{j}$ and sequences $a_{n}$,$b_{n}$ that:

$a_{n}(Z_{1}+...+Z_{n})+b_{n} \Rightarrow X$

But I don't know how to find those sequences. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How do you define the self-decomposable variables?

Comment: I define X as self-decomposable if there exists such sequence of independent random variables $Z_{n}$ and sequences of real numbers $a_{n}>0,b_{n}$ that $a_{n}(Z_{1}+...+Z_{n})+b_{n} \Rightarrow X$

Comment: Sorry but how does the accepted answer show that $X$ exponential is such that $X=cX+Y_c$ in distribution for every $c$ in $(0,1)$, for some $Y_c$ independent of $X$?

Comment: sarnow = Novsar ?

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fact: If $X_i$ has gamma distribution $\Gamma(k_i,\theta)$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Xi$ has gamma distribution $\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_i,\theta)$.
And for $c>0$ we get $cX_i$ has gamma distribution $\Gamma(k_i,c\theta)$.

What is more $\Gamma(1,\frac{1}{\lambda})=Exp(\lambda)$.

So let $Z_i$ has gamma distribution $\Gamma(\frac{1}{n},\frac{n}{\lambda})$. Then we get the equation: 
$$X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i$$
Then $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=0$.

Comment: Sorry but how does this show that $X$ exponential is such that $X=cX+Y_c$ in distribution for every $c$ in $(0,1)$, for some $Y_c$ independent of $X$?

Comment: I tried to show $X$ is self-decomposable by using the definition. I tried to find such a sequence of random variables that multiplied by some $a_n >0$ would converge to $X$.

Comment: Are you answering my query? I guess not.

Comment: I tried to use the definition, not the theorem.